# css highlight current page

Tags: css-sprites

I've found some tutorials regarding sprite navigation menu. My problem now when I make it locally, I tried to select each menu and it was not highlighted. Hover is working fine only highlighted selected menu is doesn't work.

here is the link
http://webberzsoft.com/tabmenu/services.htm

Any help would very much appreciated.

Thanks

Tirso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, all of your pages' `<body>`s have a "home" id.

For the current page to be highlighted with the CSS rules you're using, you should have corresponding body id's for each page.

Comment: hi Eli

thanks to your immediate replied.
It's work like a charm

thank you